# Value of first element in 2D string array being changed unexpectedly after forking

Tags: c, arrays, string, fork

I am writing a shell that handles piping.  I get the user input and split it into segments according to what pipes, if any, are input and put it into an array.  The first item in the array is the number of elements in the array stored as a string.  After forking, the first element in the array appears to be a zero or null, in both the parent and child process.

Code

```
char *getInput(void)
{
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufferSize);
    int counter = 0;
    int c = getchar();

    // Loop through each character in input
    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        // Ensure that the buffer can fit the next char
        if (counter <= bufferSize) // If buffer not full
        {
            buffer[counter] = c; // Add character to buffer
        }
        else // If buffer full
        {
            bufferSize = bufferSize + 1024; // Increase buffer size
            buffer[counter] = c; // Add character to buffer
        }

        c = getchar(); // Get the next char
        counter++;
    }

    // Add null to end of buffer
    if (counter <= bufferSize) // If buffer not full
    {
        buffer[counter] = '\0'; // Add null character to end of buffer
    }
    else // If buffer full
    {
        bufferSize = bufferSize + 1024; // Calculate new buffer size
        buffer = realloc(buffer, bufferSize); // Increase buffer size
        buffer[counter] = '\0'; // Add null character to end of buffer
    }

    return buffer;
}

char **split(char *input, char *delimiter)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    //char d[2] = delimiter; // Delimit string by spaces
    char *item = strtok(input, delimiter); // Gets first delimited item
    // Array of items, allocate extra slot to store array size
    char **itemArray = malloc((sizeof(char) * bufferSize) + 1); 

    while (item != NULL) // While items left in string
    {
        itemArray[counter+1] = item; // Insert into array of items
        item = strtok(NULL, delimiter); // Get next delimited item
        counter++;

        if (counter <= bufferSize) // If buffer not full
        {
            bufferSize = bufferSize + 1024; // Calculate new buffer size
            itemArray = realloc(itemArray, bufferSize); // Increase buffer size
        }
    }

    // Store size of array in first array slot
    char size = counter + 48;
    char *sizeP = &size;
    itemArray[0] = sizeP;

    return itemArray;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int loop = 1;
    char *input;
    char **segs;

    // Loop until the EOF command is used
    while (loop)
    {
        input = getInput(); // Get input line
        char *delimiter = "|";
        segs = split(input, delimiter); // Parse for pipe segments or single segment
        if (segs[1] == NULL) return 0; // EOF

        char *segsSizeChar1 = segs[0];
        int numSegs1 = *segsSizeChar1 - '0';
        printf("\nBefore Fork:\n");
        printf("Arr[0]: %i\n", numSegs1);
        printf("Arr[1]: %s\n", segs[1]);

        // Initial Fork
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();

        if (pid > 0) // Parent
        {
            char *segsSizeChar2 = segs[0];
            int numSegs2 = *segsSizeChar2 - '0';
            printf("\nIn Parent:\n");
            printf("Arr[0]: %i\n", numSegs2);
            printf("Arr[1]: %s\n", segs[1]);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) // Child
        {
            char *segsSizeChar3 = segs[0];
            int numSegs3 = *segsSizeChar3 - '0';
            printf("\nIn Child:\n");
            printf("Arr[0]: %i\n", numSegs3);
            printf("Arr[1]: %s\n", segs[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            // Catch error
        }
    }
}
```

Input

```
ls
```

Output

```
Before Fork:                                                                                               
Arr[0]: 1                                                                                                  
Arr[1]: ls                                                                                                 

In Parent:                                                                                                 
Arr[0]: -48                                                                                                
Arr[1]: ls                                                                                                 

In Child:                                                                                                  
Arr[0]: -48                                                                                                
Arr[1]: ls
```

As you can see in the parent and child, arr[0] has a zero or null value instead of a 1 (it should only be one because there is only one segment, no pipes).
Oddly enough the rest of the array appears to be fine, as selecting the next array element shows the proper value.

The issue appears to happen directly after I fork, but I am not sure why.

Comment: You have made one mistake in while loop of char *getInput(void) function,if more than 1024 char are entered you increment bufferSize  variable but not allocating memory,this will cause access to memory which is not allocated for buffer.

Comment: Ah you're right, thank you very much for catching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the following lines:

```
// Store size of array in first array slot
char size = counter + 48;
char *sizeP = &size;
itemArray[0] = sizeP;
```

You are returning the address of the local variable `size` from `split` and are dereferencing the address in:

```
  char *segsSizeChar1 = segs[0];
  int numSegs1 = *segsSizeChar1 - '0';
```

and

```
  char *segsSizeChar2 = segs[0];
  int numSegs2 = *segsSizeChar2 - '0';
```

and

```
  char *segsSizeChar3 = segs[0];
  int numSegs3 = *segsSizeChar3 - '0';
```

That is cause for undefined behavior.

You can fix that by changing those lines in `split` to:

```
char *sizeP = malloc(1);
*sizeP = counter + 48;
itemArray[0] = sizeP;
```